Balanced pulley problem from Stewart's Calculus chapter 3

I am solving the above problem from Stewart's Calculus. We have to maximize $|ED|$. Now, $|EF| = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ and using Pythagoras's theorem
$$ |BF| = \sqrt{(d-x)^2 + (r^2 - x^2)} = \sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2dx}$$
$$ |ED| = |EF| + |FD| = \sqrt{r^2-x^2} + l - \sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2dx} $$
Let $f(x) = |ED|$ and domain of $x$ is $[0, r]$. Taking derivative, we have
$$ f'(x) = \frac{-x}{(r^2 - x^2)^{1/2}} + \frac{d}{(r^2 + d^2 - 2dx)^{1/2}}$$
$f'(x)$ doesn't exist at $x = r$. This is one of the critical points. $f'(x) = 0$ for another critical point. Solving this, we get
$$ \frac{x}{(r^2 - x^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{d}{(r^2 + d^2 - 2dx)^{1/2}} $$
Using the distances in the figure, the above expression can be written as
$$ \frac{x}{|EF|} = \frac{d}{|BF|} \cdots \cdots (1)$$
Now, let $\angle \;BFE = \alpha$, and $\angle\; EFC = \beta$ and $\angle \;EBF = \delta$. Hence $\angle\; ECF = \frac{\pi}{2} - \beta$. Using law of sines for triangles $\triangle EFC$ and $\triangle BFC$, we have
$$\frac{x}{|EF|} = \frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\pi/2 - \beta)} = \frac{\sin(\beta)}{\cos(\beta)} $$
and
$$ \frac{d}{|BF|} = \frac{\sin(\alpha + \beta)}{\sin(\pi/2 - \beta)} = \frac{\sin(\alpha + \beta)}{\cos(\beta)} $$
Using, equation (1), we get $\sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\beta)$, which leads to $\alpha + \beta = \pi - \beta$. Hence, we have $\alpha + 2\beta = \pi$. Since, $\delta = \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha$, we have $\delta = 2\beta - \frac{\pi}{2}$. Now, again using law of sines in $\triangle BFC$, we have
$$ \frac{r}{\sin(2\beta - \pi/2)} = \frac{d}{\sin(\alpha + \beta)} = \frac{d}{\sin(\beta)}$$
$$ \frac{r}{-\cos(2\beta)} = \frac{d}{\sin(\beta)} $$
Now, here, $\beta$ is an acute angle, RHS is positive and so LHS must be positive. This means that $2\beta$ is between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$. So, $\beta \in (\pi/4, \pi/2)$. Now the above expression can be turned into a quadratic equation in $\sin(\beta)$.
$$ 2d \sin^2(\beta) - r \sin(\beta) - d = 0$$
Solving this leads to ($\beta$ is an acute angle here, so sine is positive root)
$$ \sin(\beta) = \frac{r + \sqrt{r^2 + 8d^2}}{4d} $$
Since, $x  = r \sin(\beta)$, finally we have the critical point
$$ x_{\text{crit}} = \frac{r}{4d}\left( r + \sqrt{r^2 + 8d^2} \right) $$
So, this is a solution to $f'(x) = 0$. Next thing is to prove that this is where $f(x)$ achieves maximum. We get the second derivative
$$ f''(x) = \frac{-r^2}{(r^2 - x^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{d^2}{(r^2 + d^2 - 2dx)^{3/2}} $$
If we can prove that $f''(x) < 0$, then it will prove that $f'(x)$ is decreasing on the domain. This means that $f'(x) > 0$ for all points below critical point and $f'(x) < 0$ for all points above critical point. Which means that $f(x)$ achieves maximum at the critical point. So, to prove $f''(x) < 0$ is to prove that
$$ \frac{d^2}{(r^2 + d^2 - 2dx)^{3/2}} < \frac{r^2}{(r^2 - x^2)^{3/2}} $$
which is to prove that
$$ \frac{d^2}{r^2} < \frac{(r^2 + d^2 - 2dx)^{3/2}}{(r^2 - x^2)^{3/2}} $$
Using various sides of triangle, we have to prove that
$$ \left( \frac{|BC|}{|FC|} \right)^2 < \left( \frac{|BF|}{|EF|} \right)^3 $$
Using law of sines, we have
$$ \frac{|BC|}{|FC|} = \frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(2\beta - \pi/2) } $$
and
$$ \frac{|BF|}{|EF|} = \frac{\sin(\pi/2)}{\sin(2\beta - \pi/2)} = \frac{1}{\sin(2\beta - \pi/2)}$$
Using these ratios, we have to prove that
$$ \frac{\sin^2(\beta)}{\sin^2(2\beta - \pi/2)} < \frac{1}{\sin^3(2\beta - \pi/2)}$$
which is to prove that
$$ \sin^2(\beta) < \frac{1}{-\cos(2\beta)} $$
Using trigonometry, we can turn this into the following quadratic equation to be proven
$$ 2 \sin^4(\beta) - \sin^2(\beta) - 1 < 0 $$
letting $t = \sin^2(\beta)$, we have to prove that $ 2t^2 - t - 1 < 0$. Since $ \beta \in (\pi/4, \pi/2)$, we have $\sin(\beta) \in (1/\sqrt{2}, 1)$. Hence $\sin^2(\beta) \in (1/2, 1)$. Or $t \in (1/2, 1)$. Now, zeros of  $ 2t^2 - t - 1$ are at $t = 1$ and $t = -0.5$. So,
solving this inequality leads to $-0.5 < t < 1$. Since $t \in (1/2, 1)$, the inequality $ 2t^2 - t - 1 < 0$ is proven. So, going back the chain of thought, it proves that $f''(x) < 0$ on the domain. And this proves that $f(x)$ achieves maximum at the critical point.
This was a hard problem from the section Problem Plus at the end of the chapter in  Stewart. Do you think there is a shorter solution here ?
Thanks
$\smile$
